# How to remove white spaces within div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following html

```
<div> <div class="first"> First Second </div>  <div class="second">Second</div>  <div class="third">Third</div> <div>
```

I want this output after removing white spaces.

First SecondSecondThird

i have used this code

```
    var str = " <div class="first"> First Second </div> <div class="second"> Second</div> <div class="third">Third</div>"; 
   str=  str.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
```

Any idea how it will work. i need this in pure javascript or anglurjs

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex [`/(>)\s+|\s+(<)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/mU6dE7/1)

```js
var str = ' <div class="first"> First Second </div> <div class="second"> Second</div> <div class="third">Third</div>';
str = str.replace(/(>)\s+|\s+(<)/g, "$1$2");
document.write(str)
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block
}
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/mU6dE7/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks man this is working like a charm .  Can you please explain this